# How to terraform output from state file with or without jq?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-state

I need to read some data from the state file, to be specific, I need to import a DNS record's IP address into my terraform configuration. I have a resource `aws_route53_record.dns_record` that I imported from the state file.

This is the output definition:

```
    output "dns_record_ip" {
      value = aws_route53_record.dns_record.*.records[0]
    }
```

And this is the actual output:

```
    dns_record_ip = toset([
      "10.10.10.100",
    ])
```

When I try to extract only the IP as a string like this:

```
    terraform output -json dns_record_ip | jq -r '.[0]'
```

I indeed get a string:

```
    10.10.10.100
```

Is there a way to achieve this by modifying the output definition so I don't have to use jq and command line since I need to use the output value in my terraform configuration? EDIT: Needed an output value so it can be used by another module.

How can I modify this:

```
    output "dns_record_ip" {
      value = aws_route53_record.dns_record.*.records[0]
    }
```

so the value of `dns_record_ip` is actually `10.10.10.100`?

ps: edited to avoid confusion

Comment: what do you mean you need to use the output value in your terraform configuration. If thats the case use the resource attribute directly in your config

Comment: I think that it will be easier if you explain what do you want to do with this output? You are mixing a few concepts.

Comment: I think the output might be required by the module. However, sets do not have indexes: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#set.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there will only be at most one instance of `aws_route53_record.dns_record` -- for example, if you have a `count` expression whose value can only be zero or one -- then you can define the output to be the single element from that list using [the `one` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/one), like this:

```
output "dns_record_ip" {
  value = one(one(aws_route53_record.dns_record[*].records))
}
```

This is a slightly more confusing use of `one` than normal because you seem to have two different one-element collections here: the `aws_route53_record.dns_record` resource as a whole has one instance, and then its `records` attribute is a one-element set. Using `one` twice like this should therefore first peel out the one set of records and then the one record from that set.

You should then be able to get this raw string, without any need for `jq`, using:

```
terraform output -raw dns_record_ip
```

If there is a possibility of this result containing more than one element in some cases then there isn't really any alternative to returning a collection, and so you would need to use `jq` in that case because JSON is the only supported machine-readable format for an output value that cannot convert to a string.